# Getting Error in simulation "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ROUTING for class: org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent"

Tags: unetstack

I'm using node.startup ={} in the simulation script to generate static routes by sending routeDiscoveryNtf at each node. I've included all headers but still, ROUTING service isn't recognized.

Simulation script is as follows, startup functionality is same for all nodes

```
    //! Simulation: 5-node network
    import org.arl.fjage.*
    import org.arl.fjage.Agent.*
    import org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform
    import org.arl.unet.sim.*
    import org.arl.unet.sim.channels.*
    import org.arl.unet.phy.*
    import org.arl.unet.phy.Physical.*
    import org.arl.unet.net.*
    import org.arl.unet.*
    import org.arl.unet.DatagramReq
    import org.arl.unet.net.Router
    import org.arl.unet.Services

    platform = RealTimePlatform
    channel.model = ProtocolChannelModel
    channel.soundSpeed = 1500.mps           // c
    channel.communicationRange = 100.m     // Rc
    channel.detectionRange = 100.m         // Rd
    channel.interferenceRange = 100.m      // Ri
    channel.pDetection = 1                  // pd
    channel.pDecoding = 1                   // pc

    simulate {
      def n1 = node '1', address: 1, location: [0.m, 0.m, 0.m], shell: true, stack:"$home/etc/initrc-stack"
    n1.startup = {
        def router = agentForService ROUTING
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:4,nextHop:1)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:2,nextHop:1)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:3,nextHop:1)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:5,nextHop:1)
      }
     def n2 =node '2', address: 2, location: [70.m, 0.m, 0.m], shell:5102, stack: "$home/etc/initrc-stack"
  n2.startup = {
    def router = agentForService ROUTING
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:4,nextHop:2)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:1,nextHop:2)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:5,nextHop:2)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:3,nextHop:4)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:3,nextHop:1)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:1,nextHop:5)

  }
  def n3 = node '3', address: 3, location: [-70.m, 0.m, 0.m], shell: 5103, stack:"$home/etc/initrc-stack"
  n3.startup = {
    def router = agentForService ROUTING
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:4,nextHop:3)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:1,nextHop:3)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:5,nextHop:3)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:2,nextHop:4)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:2,nextHop:1)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:2,nextHop:5)
  }
  def n4 = node '4', address: 4, location: [0.m, 70.m, 0.m], shell: 5104, stack:"$home/etc/initrc-stack"
  n4.startup = {
    def router = agentForService ROUTING
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:1,nextHop:4)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:2,nextHop:4)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:3,nextHop:4)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:5,nextHop:1)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:5,nextHop:2)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to:5,nextHop:3)
  }
  def n5 = node '5', address: 5, location: [0.m, -70.m, 0.m], shell: 5105, stack:"$home/etc/initrc-stack"
  n5.startup = {
    def router = agentForService ROUTING
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 1 , nextHop:5)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 3 , nextHop:5)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 2 , nextHop:5)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 4 , nextHop:1)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 4 , nextHop:2)
    router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 4 , nextHop:3)
  }
}
```

Simulation Error is as follows:

```
SEVERE: <3> > Exception in agent: simulator
SEVERE: <4> > Exception in agent: simulator
SEVERE: <1> > Exception in agent: simulator
SEVERE: <5> > Exception in agent: simulator
SEVERE: <2> > Exception in agent: simulator
```

Though stack is being loaded on every node, Routes are not being created.

Log file stats are :

```
1562654374493|SEVERE|<1>@36:run|Exception in agent: simulator
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ROUTING for class: org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent
Stack trace: ...
org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent.propertyMissing(initrc.groovy:216) ...
org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent.getProperty(initrc.groovy) ...
ping-sim2$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(ping-sim2.groovy:37)
ping-sim2$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(ping-sim2.groovy) ...
org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent.this$dist$invoke$2(initrc.groovy)
org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent$1.methodMissing(initrc.groovy) ...
org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent$1.action(initrc.groovy:172)
org.arl.fjage.Agent.run(Agent.java:777) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `ROUTING` service's canonical name is `org.arl.unet.Services.ROUTING`. So you might have to use that string instead of just `ROUTING`

`def router = agentForService org.arl.unet.Services.ROUTING`

Comment: still, same error is there 
No such property: org for class: org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationAgent

Comment: Updated the answer above. Had missed the fact that ROUTING was a member of the Services class. So it should be org.arl.unet.Services.ROUTING. I tested out your Simulation in UnetStack1.3 and it runs without errors.

Comment: Thank You for the response, sir, It works fine now.